# Return comment_closure ("close comments," "enable comments"

Tags: basecamp

One can close commenting on a Basecamp message using the utility/(...) 3 dots menu.

Is there a way to retrieve the comment_closure status of a message using the API?

I don't find anything about this in the documentation.